# How can I match a contour-plot's height with the colorbar height?

Tags: python, size, contour

How can I keep the size of the colorbar as it is, and make the contour plot bigger, so they match?

[image: Snapshot of my app showing that the contour plot is too small]

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you [edit] your question to show your current code that isn't working correctly, ideally a full [mcve].  From [ask]: *Help others reproduce the problem...  if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some...Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*

Comment: Please also [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) the question with the library or framework you are using to make the contour plot.  The general-purpose tags [tag:contour] and [tag:size] don't indicate what library you are using.  By tagging your question with the libraries & frameworks you are using you are more likely to attract the attention of a subject matter expert who can answer questions about those libraries.